# How to introduce CSS rules in Tumblr environment without affecting the theme?

Tags: php, html, css, themes, tumblr

I needed few simple changes to the style sheet files and I successfully managed to make these changes offline through Google Chrome Inspector but when I tried every time to implement these changes on the Tumblr theme, the blog breaks down and becomes a big mess.

Can you guys tell me please how to tackle this issue? What's the right approach or the appropriate workflow to introduce such changes of this nature without disrupting the theme?

Thanks in advance for your time and cooperation.

Comment: If you don't show how you do things, nobody is able to answer you. By the way, there might be name conflicts.

Comment: Unless you show us snippets of the files your'e trying to fix and the code you're using to "implement" the fix, we're not going to be able to help and this question will likely be closed.

Comment: Do you want me to post the theme file here? It's 500 line long and I don't how to make a smaller snippet out of it without sacrificing relevancy or clarity ...

Comment: @FreelanceTime No. If it's just a "few simple changes to the style sheet files" you should be able to show us specifically where you are trying to change something (the original code), how you are trying to do it (your code), and what you want it do (a short explanation of what you're trying to accomplish.)

Answer (score 2):

Tumblr themes should have the ability to insert Custom CSS.

When inside your 'Customize Theme' panel, open the 'Advanced' tab (at the bottom), there will be a box that will allow you to add Custom CSS. Add the changes you'd like to make there.

If you don't see the changes, your theme might not be optimized to accept the custom CSS that you've entered.

Click on the 'Edit HTML' button and search for `{CustomCSS}`. If you can't find it, then you'll need to add the following code before the `</head>` tag.

```
<style type="text/css">
    {CustomCSS}
</style>
```

That should do it!

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful answer, gray. Can you tell me please how is this custom CSS different from the everyday CSS?

Comment: It is no different, it's just what Tumblr calls CSS that hasn't been bundled with the theme already.